# how to achieve cache auto refresh in tomcat server for Grails application

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails, caching

We have a web-application running on tomcat servers and we maintain cache data on the servers. We are facing issue whenever we get new data that is not fetched in the cache and not able to display on the UI. We need to restart the server every time whenever we get new traffic in order to see the new data on the UI. Below is the hibernate config part ...

```
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache=true
cache.use_query_cache=true
cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
show_sql=true
}
```

let me explain the issue with example ... say I maintain `Services` in cache and this `Services` is coming from `OracleDB`. I got new `Services` in the DB and when I query in the DB for the same I do see new `Services` but when I look into the UI I am missing the new ones. I am able to see these new `Services` only when I restart the Tomcat Server.

I would like to know is there any way to auto refresh the cache without restarting the tomcat server to get the data displayed in UI. Thanks.

I am using `ehcache-core.2.4.6` and didn't configured `ehcache.xml` in my app, I found that two caches are maintained and those values set to below ...

```
      CACHE                                                CONFIGURATION
org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache      ehcache [maxElementsInMemory = 10000, overflowToDisk = true, maxElementsOnDisk = 10000000, eternal = false, timeToLiveSeconds = 120, timeToIdleSeconds = 120, memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU, diskPersistent = false]  
org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache   ehcache [maxElementsInMemory = 10000, overflowToDisk = true, maxElementsOnDisk = 10000000, eternal = false, timeToLiveSeconds = 120, timeToIdleSeconds = 120, memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU, diskPersistent = false]
```

If I need to configure the ehcache.xml to fix the issue, do I need to change the `timeToIdleSeconds="120"` and `timeToLiveSeconds="120"` values or do I need to add anymore attributes to the config. I want the cache to be refreshed automatically whenever there is change in data from DB. Let me know if if this is not clear enough to explain the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not completely off topic here :-) Basically you need to configure your ehcache and tell it you want it to treat various caches. That's usually done using the `ehcache.xml` file (in your `grails-app/conf` folder). An example could be:

```
<ehcache>
   <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
        timeToLiveSeconds="2600"
        overflowToDisk="false">
   </defaultCache>

   <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="300" />
   <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        timeToIdleSeconds="400" timeToLiveSeconds="1200" />

   ...
</ehcache>
```

To inspect your cache you could use Java Melody plugin (i.e. `compile ":grails-melody:1.55.0"` in your `BuildConfig.groovy`). Some don't like it but it can give you a nice insight into your application, including caching. Just make sure it's not deployed into production ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... in my application we didn't configure the ehcache.xml,, instead we are using the `ehcache-core.2.4.6` one and below is default cache ...

Comment: <defaultCache
maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
eternal="false" 
timeToIdleSeconds="120" 
timeToLiveSeconds="120"
overflowToDisk="true" maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
diskPersistent="false"
diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
AND
org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache [maxElementsInMemory = 10000, overflowToDisk = true, maxElementsOnDisk = 10000000, eternal = false, timeToLiveSeconds = 120, timeToIdleSeconds = 120, memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU, diskPersistent = false]
same as above for org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache as well

Comment: the ehcache is using the default values in ehcache-core.2.4.6 , I am not sure whether these values makes difference for my issue... any suggestions please ...